# Why aren't iOS modules available for user frameworks?

Tags: ios, ios7

Xcode 5.0 (iOS 7.0 SDK) adds an awesome new feature -- modules (see WWDC 2013 Session 404).

This is great because it speeds up compile time and eliminates the need to manually link frameworks. Well, *Apple* frameworks.

The Apple Engineer in said WWDC talk specifically noted that "modules are not available for user frameworks". I understand this to mean that it's not possible (or perhaps will lead to rejection?) to do such.

Why not?

**EDIT**

This question is not meant to question "is it right" for such limitation. Rather, "is there some limitation with modules that prevents creating a module of a user framework"? Or perhaps, a security vulnerability... not sure why this would have security issues, as it would still be a static framework?

Comment: Don't question the Borg.

Comment: Close votes are for "opinion based". I'm not asking for an opinion here... is this due to some limitation in modules?

Comment: This is best for the clang or objective c mailing lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create modules for user frameworks. It's documented here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html

But the process is complicated, you need to know what you're doing or it will fall apart, and Apple doesn't currently provide any documentation or tools explaining how to make it work.

There is no difference between custom frameworks and apple's official frameworks. The only difference is Apple's frameworks have been bundled into a module by someone who deeply understands how the compiler works, which is currently necessary to create a module.

Comment: Awesome. I suppose the Apple Engineer must have meant "modules aren't available for user frameworks... unless you create them." :P This point isn't very clear in the talk. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @JRG-Developer The primary goal of Modules is make compiling code faster when linking to a large framework. Since Apple makes all of the truly large frameworks available, it's only important for them to implement Modules. Hopefully it will be easier for third party frameworks to join the party but it's not a priority.

Answer (score -1):

This is just my guess.

The new module works similar to pre-compiled header with automatic static library linking. The most benefit is come from that no need to parse same set of headers in different compilation unit. Compiler will pre-compiled the headers of the framework and make them reusable.

The main problem is that one project cannot have two pre-compiled header. If the header is pre-compiled, the content must be identical in every compilation unit (.m file).

Let's assume you **can** create custom module:

mymodule.h

```
#ifndef MyCountType 
#    define MyCountType int
#endif
static MyCountType counter_per_file;
```

somefile.m

```
#define MyCountType double

#import "mymodule.h" // or @import "mymodule.h"
```

someotherfilie.m

```
#define MyCountType unsigned int

#import "mymodule.h" // or @import "mymodule.h"
```

So what should be the type of `counter_per_file`? When pre-compiling `mymodule.h`, the compiler have no way to know the type of `MyCountType`, it may be `int`, or anything.

Comment: One of the points of modules is to prevent issues like this. In your example, `MyCountType` would always be `int` when using `@import` (or if the compiler converts your `#import` to `@import` -- I know it does this for Apple frameworks, not sure if it does for custom ones).

Comment: @JacobLukas I don't understand your point. The whole point of my example is that someone may want to change `MyCountType` for specific file, with module system, this can't be done. Someone will see unexpected result and compiler can't give any warning about it.

Comment: As documented here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#problems-with-the-current-model They prevent these sorts of interactions as they are usually unintended